What do I NEED?
What do I...


(-11,-10,7)            (-16,-17,7)  (9,12,5)(13,-2,5)    (-2,-8,7)(-16,-17,9)     (10,12,9)(-16,-17,5)
(-4,-6,11)(6,7,11)      (-7,-10,9)  (6,7,7)              (−2,-2,3)                (13,16,9)       (15,7,3)
(10,9,11)    (7,9,5)    (13,12,11)  (−14,-15,7)          (13,12,3)(3,0,11)        (-9,-6,3)         (8,5,3)
(13,14,7)       (3,1,5)(-9,-10,11)  (3,2,3)              (-2,-2,9)                (0,-2,11)      (−2,−8,11)
(-2,-6,7)             (-16,-17,11)  (15,-2,7)(15,14,11)  (-14,-15,11)(-11,-13,9)  (10,12,7)(-14,-10,3)


                                                  (-16,-17,3)
                                           (-7,-8,3)       (3,0,7)
                                                           (3,2,9)
                                                   (-11,-10,5)

                                                   (6,5,9)



You need

 PERSPECTIVE


 If you plot out the coordinate points in 3D following the (x,y,z) formats presented by the puzzle and look at the result from a certain perspective.

You get

 
PERSP!

If we look at it from the back of this we get:

 

ECTIVE!


Is this right now?

I believe BG's saying that your answer is missing something, not that "missing something" is part of the question. (What happens if you look at those same points from a different angle?)

Also https://www.desmos.com/3d/fq9jm0jjjg if anyone wants to have a play for themselves (feel free to edit in)
